# Do game studios look at personal projects when hiring?

Tags: career

I am 17 and I have spent the past 5 years making games for fun. But now I am faced with college and it might be time to get serious about this hobby.

So do Game Studios want to see personal games or 3d models in resumes, or will they only care about professional level work? To a lesser extent my question is also when would a company hire a high school student and why?

As always with these sites I feel like i'm walking on eggshells, so if this is posted in the wrong place, or if i'm breaking any rules please tell me.

Comment: There's not actually a correct answer for this, since it'll depend on the game studio and on what kind of position you're applying for. As with many careers, if you're applying for an entry level position, professional level work isn't expected, and whatever examples you can provide to support the evidence of your skills is a bonus to you. Check out the concept of a portfolio and see about creating one to complement your résumé.

Comment: Ah, what should I do with my question now? Do I delete it? And also, thanks, a portfolio sounds like an obvious solution for me to miss, but I didn't think about it because i've never needed one before.

Comment: You can leave the question, if people search for something similar in the future, they'll know it's off topic and perhaps get some insight from my comment or the answer below.

Comment: Despite the non-games focus, you may try http://workplace.stackexchange.com as they don't mind soft questions like this one. They even have a "portfolio" tag.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that this existed, otherwise I would have posted there, or maybe I would have found my answers already. Thank You.

Comment: Short answer: definitely yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the game or model you made for a personal project demonstrates your skill well, it's definitely worth including in your portfolio.

Just bear in mind that more is not necessarily better. A piece that represents a great learning experience for you on the road to the more polished work in your portfolio might stand out to an interviewer as a weak point, and raise questions about the consistency of your work. So, ruthlessly pare your portfolio down to only your very best work.

Comment: Thank you, I think I need to limit my scope to start completing some portfolio worthy work, based on what you have said.